# Visual Studio Code extension: Keep flag in memory between extension restarts

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm in the process of writing a Visual Studio Code extension which accesses a remote file system in a way so that the remote files can be displayed, edited, ... in the local VSCode instance. For that, I have to connect to that remote host and the call the API function

`vscode.workspace.updateWorkspaceFolders ()`.

Now that functions always restarts the extension, there does not seem to be a way around that. So I need to know that the extension has to reconnect to the remote host again after the restart in just that situation. The obvious solution is a transient boolean flag in memory, which is not kept between different application runs but between extension restarts.

Is that possible somehow ?

There are various other configuration storages, secret storages and settings which can easily be accessed, but all of them are permanent (kept between application runs). Is there some simple "boolean flag in memory" solution which is not discarded when the extension restarts ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I found part of a solution: The `vscode.env.sessionId` can be used to determine if the application has been restarted or if just the extension has been reloaded. So keeping that id in a permanent configuration storage might be a workaround and if that stored id is still matching the current session id, it's an extension restart and no application restart. Only drawback: That id is fake (`someValue.sessionId`) if the extension is currently debugged, so this will work only in production mode.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter that the other storage solutions are permanent, if you can find an indicator, that tells you the workspace is updated. Then set your flag in any permanent storage and remove it on `deactivate`, when the condition for the workspace update is not true.

One example that doesn't use `deactivate()` would be: you call `vscode.workspace.updateWorkspaceFolders()` yourself, so you know you are the reason for that restart. Maybe only set this permanent flag in this single case and handle it on `activate`?

Comment: No, that does not work, because there is no way to distinguish between `deactivate ()` being called when the extension is going to restart or the application is going to shutdown. Only in the second case setting back the then permanent flag would have to be done.

Comment: And what about the second paragraph, which doesn't use `deactivate`, actually? It relies solely on the fact that you know when the workspace is reloaded and can set that flag.

Comment: I'm afraid this leads to the same problem. 'updateWorkspaceFolders ()' will deactivate the extension and so the flag set before is gone, because its lifetime is bound to the extension.